# Erro ao baixar o intellij

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

Estou tentando baixar o intellij mas toda vez que eu configuro e inicio um projeto novo da esse erro:

Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\allan\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init4.gradle' (C:\Users\allan.gradle\caches\6.8\scripts\cp6898nl7qj2vxvon6eixl7up).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

Acho que o problema tá na versão desse BuildScript, porém não sei como chegar nele nem se é isso mesmo, alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: a possibilidade ai é que a versão do gradle que você está não suporta o java 16, sugiro atualizar o gradle (ou dar downgrade na sua versão do java)

Comment: Eu usei a 15, mesmo assim deu o mesmo erro, será que eu rebaixo mais pra ver?

Answer (score -1):

Use JDK 11, funcionou para mim.

[image: selecione 11]